# How To extract the values from csv file in ant?

Tags: ant

`Washington`
`New York`
`New Delhi`
`India`
`United States Of America`

In ant I want to extract all the values as separate values like washington, new, delhi, india, united, states, of, america. Altough I am able to extract them line wise as

```
<loadfile property="message" srcFile="../Ant_Scripts/Name.csv"/>
<target name="init">
<for list="${message}" delimiter="${line.separator}" param = "val">
<echo message=${val}/>
```

but I am not able to extract them as individual units that is once I got New Delhi or New York I should be able to get New and Delhi seprately also.

---

> can you please post your ant script – Satya

```
    <loadfile property="message" srcFile="../Ant_Scripts/Name.csv"/>
    <target name="init">
         <for list="${message}" delimiter="${line.separator}" param = "val">
              <sequential>
                   <echo>$val</echo>
              </sequential>
         </for>
    </target>
</project>
```

This code will print all the names line by line, but after this I want to break those lines on the basis of space.

Comment: can you please post your ant script

Comment: <loadfile property="message" srcFile="../Ant_Scripts/Name.csv"/> <target name="init">              <for list="${message}" delimiter="${line.separator}" param = "val"> <sequential> <echo>$val</echo>                                                      </sequential>                                                        </for>                                                               </target>                                                            </project>                    this code will print all the names line by line but after this i want to break those lines on the basis of space

Comment: please use the edit link below the post, to add the information about the buildfile.

Comment: ok i am new here so don't know too much

Comment: It is time to accept answer(s) ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is one fundamental error:

http://dailyraaga.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/ant-for-loop/

- you have to access the CSV element with @{param}, no ${param}. This loop uses attributes, not properties ;)

There is also one task you might find handy for your line seperation needs:

- http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fixcrlf.html